# Is this CSST bonding proper?

Tags: natural-gas, csst, bonding

Is it okay for the 6 AWG copper bonding to come in contact with the CSST?

Notes:

- Distances are not drawn to scale; CSST is about 60 feet with bends and turns
- Assume the black iron is properly grounded to the electric panel, etc...

[image]

Comment: Is there a dedicated bonding path from the black iron to the grounding electrode system (or main panel) that uses 6AWG or thicker wire?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel yes, I mentioned that in the notes.